# list with a repetitive group

Tags: list

I want to create a list with various items and one repetitive area, I mean:

client name

client car

---

item name

item color

---

item name

item color

---

various items for a client, how can I create this list?

Comment: I've seen also that it can be done with form library instead of list forms (I have to include calculated fields and hide some fields depending on the fields selected)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is setup two lists, one with clients, one with the items, and have a lookup field between the two. Then you can import your lists into the same page to give this kind of dashboard look, check out http://davidlozzi.com/2012/08/02/creating-an-item-detail-dashboard-view-of-your-joined-lists-in-sharepoint-2010/, I walk through how. As far as the formatting of the views, there are several options available in the list view settings, one may suffice for the grouped look you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks David, that's is a good idea, with this approach would I be able to edit the data in the item detail dashboard, for example adding a new row-detail?